# Setting default linker for gcc on Solaris

Tags: gcc, linker, solaris, autoconf

I'm trying to compile Python 3.2.3 on Solaris 10 sparc, and the configure script fails at an early stage ("checking wheter the C compiler works").

Checking config.log suggests that the reason is gcc uses the Solaris linker under /usr/ccs/bin instead of the GNU linker, and tries to pass linker flags that are not supported. I have GNU ld installed as well, and PATH it set to point to its bin dir (it is listed earlier than /usr/ccs/bin).

My question is how can I force gcc to use the GNU linker. I haven't found any trivial solutions for it.

I believe the problem is not strictly related to python, I had the same issue earlier for other software using autoconf.

Comment: Selecting which linker to use is something done when building gcc. Trying to change it later doesn't work. So the question would be: where does your gcc come from? And what config.log message makes you believe that this is the issue?

Comment: It is a self-built gcc. When I have compiled it, I have added the --with-gnu-ld flag in the hope it will fix my problem, but with no luck.

Comment: Ah, so compiling a trivial helloworld probably fails as well and this has nothing to do with python then? Did you use --with-ld=/path/to/the/right/ld? Is there a particular reason you want to use GNU ld, which is not recommended on solaris?

Comment: No, Solaris ld is ok for me as well if it works. Previously, I have tried with a gcc that has been compiled without the gnu ld option, with the same outcome. Afterwards, I have rebuilt gcc with the above option. So in short I would be also happy if I can make configure not to produce any linker flags that is incompatible with the sun ld. I will try to build a gcc once again without the gnu ld option.

Comment: I have recompiled my gcc to use the solaris linker and it seems the problem has gone. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all verify which version of `gcc` your are using via `which gcc` command. Second rename your currnt gcc to gcc.bak using `mv /usr/sfw/bin/gcc /usr/sfw/bin/gcc.bak`. And finally add the path to your new c compiler to the `$PATH` variable.